# MVC LINQ SELECT ALL when parameter is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have a controller like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string xyear, string xmonth)
{
      var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin)
                        .Where(c => (c.Year == xyear) && (c.Month == xmonth));

      return View(query.ToList());
}
```

I want to load the List when a button is clicked. When `xyear` is null and `xmonth` is set to `1`... Then The list will load all data with `Month = 1`. Or, If `xyear` is set to `2019` and `xmonth` is set to null... Then the list will load all data with `Year = 2019`. ff.

Anyone have an idea for this case?
Really appreciated

Comment: Predicate builder is one way to go. There are good examples if you Google it. I use the albahari (see [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which is on NuGet.

Comment: the concept here is flawed, have a rethink about what you actually want to do. But you are looking for a string array and using contains in your linq expression

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public ActionResult Index(string xyear, string xmonth)
{
      var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin)
                        .Where(c => (c.Year == xyear || xyear == null) && (c.Month == xmonth || xmonth == null));

      return View(query.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. But when I fill one of the parameter. It doesn't load the List.

Comment: I think this brings back either the specified year or only those records where the year is `null` rather than all years. Same with months.

Comment: @PeterSmith, any idea?

Comment: i think there is a flaw in the concept here if that is what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var predicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.New<Master>(true);
predicateBuilder = xyear != null : predicateBuilder.And(c => c.Year == xyear): 
                                   predicateBuilder;
predicateBuilder = xmonth != null : predicateBuilder.And(c => c.Month == xmonth) : 
                                    predicateBuilder;
var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin)
                        .Where(peridicateBuilder);
return View(query.ToList());
```

This assumes you use the NuGet PredicateBuilder package.

This only adds in the Month or Year `where` clauses if the parameter is not `null`.

An alternative without predicate builder is:

```
var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin);
 if (xyear =! null)
 {
    query = query.Where(c => (c.Year == xyear));
}
if (xmonth = !null)
{
    query = query.Where(c => (c.Year == xmonth));
}

return View(query.ToList());
```

Comment: this is over complicated

Comment: Do you have a simpler alternative. I would be interested to see it.

Comment: var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin)
                        .Where(c => c.Year == null) && c.Month == "1")); - exactly what is asked for

Comment: @Morpheus This is an example only and `Year` is never null. The question also goes on ask "Or, If `xyear` is set to 2019 and `xmonth`..." Your answer will always return an empty list.

Comment: so use string.IsNullOrEmpty() obviously the data would have to match this condition

Answer (score 0):

why not chain your `where` depending on the null?

```
var query = db.Masters.Include(m => m.MasterOrigin).AsQueryable();

if (xyear != null && xMonth == null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Year == xyear);
}
if (xyear == null && xMonth != null)
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.Month == xMonth);
}
var result = query.ToList();

return View(result);
```

or if you are sure that when `xYear != null`, `xMonth == null` then

```
if (xyear != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Year == xyear);
}
if (xMonth != null)
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.Month == xMonth);
}

var result = query.ToList();

return View(result);
```

Comment: Why the `AsQueryable`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado oh, sorry, force of habit, but with or without it would both return `IQueryable`